# IntelliJ noclassdeffounderror while running application

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When running our application in IntelliJ by using Run command, the application is throwing below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.aexp.sec.crypto.VECrypto
        at com.aexp.comms.util.CryptoUtil.getVECrypto(CryptoUtil.java:78)
```

Even though class file is available in ssaascrypto-2.5.1.jar file which builds successfully and is configured in external library in IntelliJ. But it's throwing above error. Any help is appreciated.

Adding the full stack trace exception here.

```
Exception in thread "cb-computations-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.aexp.sec.crypto.VECrypto
    at com.aexp.comms.util.CryptoUtil.getVECrypto(CryptoUtil.java:78)
    at com.aexp.comms.util.CryptoUtil.getInstance(CryptoUtil.java:44)
    at com.aexp.comms.orchestrator.processor.CommunicationConsumerVerticle.initialize(CommunicationConsumerVerticle.java:179)
    at com.aexp.comms.orchestrator.processor.CommunicationConsumerVerticle.lambda$start$0(CommunicationConsumerVerticle.java:143)
    at rx.Single$11.onSuccess(Single.java:1803)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeSingle$1.onCompleted(OnSubscribeSingle.java:55)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:860)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onCompleted(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:101)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onCompleted(Subscribers.java:225)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: What's the entire stack trace of the exception? What command line do you use to run this application successfully?

Comment: It looks like the classloader has a problem to find the class, but it could be that an error occurred during loading the class. this means that some static code have thrown an exception during class initialisation.

Comment: @tgdavies - Added the entire stack trace exception above.

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and fully rebuild project? Is it reproducible with some sample project example?